# Servidor no ejecuta código php

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache2

Hola estoy empezando a programar con php.

El problema está que al subir el archivo al servidor local, el navegador solicita el documento "regístrate.html". Después, introduzco los datos en el formulario. Pero el servidor no ejecuta las instrucciones php del documento "registro.php", sino que las interpreta literalmente.

**Esto es lo que recibo, como he dicho el código php sin ejecutar**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os adjunto el documento html **"regístrate.html"** que tiene que enviar los datos al documento php.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>


  </head>
  <body>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/WEB/estilos.css">
      <div  class="slideshow-container2">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="http://localhost/WEB/images/MorganMaassen_Surf_2.jpg" alt="The Woods"style="width:100%">
        <div class="text" id="infoFoto">
          <ul class="menu">
              <li class="NavLi1"><a href="http://localhost/WEB/inicio.html" class="NavLink">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="NavLi1"><a href="http://localhost/WEB/galeriaPublica.html" class="NavLink">Descubre</a>
              </li>
              <li class="NavLi2"><a href="http://localhost/WEB/login.html" class="NavLink">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="NavLi2"><a href="http://localhost/WEB/registrate.php" class="NavLink">Registrate</a>
              </li>
              <li class="NavLi3">
              <form>
                  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Buscar">
              </form>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="text5">
          <form action="/WEB/regsitrar.php" method="post">
          <label for="email"><p class="textoColorPaginaInicio">E-mail</p></label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail">
          <label for="nomreUsu"><p class="textoColorPaginaInicio">Nombre de usuario</p></label>
          <input type="text" id="nombreUsu∫" name="E-mail" placeholder="">
          <br>
          <label for="contrasena1"><p class="textoColorPaginaInicio">Contraseña</p></label>
          <input type="text" id="contrasena1" name="Contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña">
          <label for="contrasena2"><p class="textoColorPaginaInicio">Confirma contraseña</p></label>
          <input type="text" id="contrasena2" name="Contraseña" placeholder="Confirma contraseña">
          <input type="submit" value="Registrate" >
        </form>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center"> <span class="dot"></span> <span class="dot"></span> <span
        class="dot"></span> </div>
      </div>


</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Aquí os dejo el documento php, **"registro.php"**. A priori, no parece ser un problema de sintaxis.

```
<?php 
  $nombreServidor = "127.0.0.1";
  $Usuario= "root";
  $Contrasena = "******";
  $nombreBD = "PROYECTO_WEB";
  $nombreUsu = $_POST["nombre"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $contrasenaUsu1 = $_POST["contrasena1"];
  $contrasenaUsu2 = $_POST["contrasena2"];
  $flag = True;
  //Creamos la conexion y selccionamos la base de datos proyecto_web
  $conexion = mysqli_connect($nombreServidor,$Usuario,$Contrasena,$nombreBD);
  if(!$conexion){
    die("CONEXION FALLIDA:" .mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  echo "Conectado con exito";
  $sql2 = "SELECT NomreUsuarioBD, Email FROM USUARIO";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
  // COMPRUEBO QUE LOS EL NOMBRE NO EXISTA
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
              if($fila["NombreCompleto"] == $nomreUsu || $fila["Email"]== $email){
                $flag=true;
              }
              else{
                $flag=False;
              }
  }
  if($flag==False)
  {
    if($contrasena1 == $contrasena2)
    {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO USUARIO(Email, Contrasena, NombreCompleto)
      VALUES ($email, $contrasenaUsu1, $nombreUsu)";
      if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql))
      {
          echo `Nuevo registro creado con éxito`;
      } else
      {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexion);
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    echo `Las cotraseñas no coinciden`;
  }

  mysqli_close($conexion);


?>
```

Comment: Puede deberse a cientos de motivos. Para empezar, ejecuta el PHP en localhost? si haces un index.php en la raíz y le metes únicamente <?php phpinfo(); ?> que pasa?. ¿Que SO utilizas? ¿Has probado a escribir php -v ? Puede deberse a que tienes el PHP mal configurado, el VH si utilizas, etc.

Comment: apache no sabe como procesar php asi que lo sirve como texto, que sistema operativo es?

Comment: si estas empezando lo mejor seria utilizar un entorno ya preparado como [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html)

Comment: utilizo mac os x mojave

Comment: fijate en `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` si hay un bloque que tiene varios `LoadModule` si está el que dice `#LoadModule php7_module ` le borras el `#` y reinicias apache, si no está tendríamos que ver que versión de php tenes instalada

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado. Efectivamente como dice algo tenía que modificar el script http.conf y decomentar varias lineas.

Comment: Y tiene PHP instalado en el serivdor?

Comment: Una pregunta, estás ocupando Xampp en tu Mac? si es así, asegúrate de tener tu proyecto en la carpeta xampp/htdocs.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que Apache no tiene activado en modulo para **PHP**, en mi caso me sucedió cuando decidí subir la versión de `php7.4` a `php8`, mi entorno es ubuntu, ejecute el comando `a2enmod php8.0` y reinicié el servicio de apache `systemctl restart apache2.service` luego de esto el problema esta solucionado.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta es un comentario. Además por navegador parece e ser que está en macOS